# How to access URL parameters in named views using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am clicking on an anchor tag `<a href="/boof?{{sid}}&{{qid}}">boofing</a>` and trying to access the URL parameters values into my `app.js` but I am getting `null` values for `$scope`, `$stateParam`, `$state`.

**app.js**

```
...
.state('bar', {
    url: '/boof?sid&qid',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/a.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
                //not getting $scope, $stateParams, $state                
            }
        },

        'foo@bar': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/b.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
                //not getting  $scope, $stateParams, $state                  
            }
        },

        ...
    }
})
...
```

**a.html**

```
<div ui-view="foo"></div>
<div ui-view="xyz"></div>
```

**b.html**

```
<div>
    //stuff using data from $scope, $stateParams, $state
</div>
```

Could somebody help me understand why am I getting `null` values for `$scope`, `$stateParams`, `$state`.

Also, could I just do a `controller: 'myController'` as below and access the `$stateParams`, `$state` in `myController`?

**app.js**

```
...
.state('bar', {
    url: '/boof?sid&qid',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/a.html',
            controller: 'myController'                
            }
        },

        'foo@bar': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/b.html',
            controller: 'myController'                  
            }
        },

        ...
    }
})
...


myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$state', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state){

    //accessing $stateParams and $state here

} ]);
```

I tried to do it, but I was getting a `null` value for both `$stateParams`  and `$state`.

Comment: Will `/boof?{{sid}}&{{qid}}` generate a valid url? It will generate a url like `/boof?1&2`. Whereas I think you wanted something like `/boof?sid=1&qid=2`.

Comment: Try to access using $routeParams...

Comment: @Rifat: Yep, it worked with `/boof?sid={{sid}}&qid={{qid}}`. Thanks.